# Using Context in Android Studio to call PackageManager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-context

I am in the process of writing an app that will use WiFi Aware to publish a service yet I cannot get passed the initial step of validating whether or not the device supports the service. The API (from Google here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware) specifies to use this line of code:

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_AWARE);
```

However, I cannot just put this into my MainActivity class since I have not instantiated an object called "context". I have tried looking around for answers and have not found any that work. Any form of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

It seems to be that using the method by itself works however it will cause the app to crash unless it is called within a method (such as my `Publish()` method). I have attached my code below for reference. Thank you.

My Code:

```
package com.patrickutz.wifiawarepublish;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.aware.AttachCallback;
import android.net.wifi.aware.WifiAwareManager;
import android.net.wifi.aware.WifiAwareSession;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.wifi.aware.PublishConfig;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

// Constant values of WifiAwareManager
String state_change = WifiAwareManager.ACTION_WIFI_AWARE_STATE_CHANGED;
int data_init = WifiAwareManager.WIFI_AWARE_DATA_PATH_ROLE_INITIATOR;
int data_resp = WifiAwareManager.WIFI_AWARE_DATA_PATH_ROLE_RESPONDER;

public void publish(View view) {

    // Check whether or not device supports WiFi Aware
    boolean hasWiFiAware = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_AWARE);

    // Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(this, message, duration);
    // Messages for whether or not device has WiFi Aware
    Toast hasAware = Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Aware Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Toast noAware = Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Aware Unsupported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if (hasWiFiAware) {
        hasAware.show();
    } else {
        noAware.show();
    }

    System.out.println(hasWiFiAware);

    // Create WiFiAwareManager object
    WifiAwareManager wifiAwareManager = (WifiAwareManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_AWARE_SERVICE);

    // Check if WiFi Aware is available
    boolean awareAvailable = wifiAwareManager.isAvailable();

    // Messages for whether or not WiFi Aware is available
    Toast isAvailable = Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Aware Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Toast notAvailable = Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Aware Unsupported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if (awareAvailable) {
        isAvailable.show();
    } else {
        notAvailable.show();
    }

//        AttachCallback attachCallback = new AttachCallback();
//        Handler handler = new Handler();
//
//        wifiAwareManager.attach(attachCallback, handler);


//        private static final String AWARE_FILE_SHARE_SERVICE_NAME = "Test Publish";
//        PublishConfig config = new PublishConfig.Builder()
//                .setServiceName(AWARE_FILE_SHARE_SERVICE_NAME)
//                .build();


    // Get the text views
    TextView showStateChangeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stateChangeTextView);
    TextView showDataPathRoleInitTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataPathRoleInitTextView);
    TextView showDataPathRoleRespTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataPathRoleRespTextView);

    // Display the new values of current state in the text view.
    showStateChangeTextView.setText("State: " + state_change);
    showDataPathRoleInitTextView.setText("Data Initiator: " + Integer.toString(data_init));
    showDataPathRoleRespTextView.setText("Data Responder: " + Integer.toString(data_resp));

  }
}
```

Comment: Please post more code. Often you can use 'this' where context is needed but it depends on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to initialize the `Context` object. Activity in the hierarchy is child class of Context.

You can simply call `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_AWARE);` in your `Activity` class. Don't have to explicitly initialize the `Context`

Comment: That works! However for some reason it only works if I call the method within my `publish()` method (which is executed when the button is pushed). If I try to call `getPackageManager()...` outside my `publish()` method then the app crashes. I have updated my question to include my code. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickUtz how are you calling the method outside the `publish()` and what is the error?

Comment: Snippet of code showing how I call the method outside publish() :

`// Check whether or not device supports WiFi Aware
    boolean hasWiFiAware = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_AWARE);

    public void publish(View view) {`           and the error states -->      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this Google Tutorial I'm looking that it is a simple way to show us that a `context` is necessary to call this methods. Then, inside `activity`, this variable instantiated is unnecessary because her already exists, so, just call `getPackageManager()...`